# There was an error fetching the like box for the specified page

Tags: facebook-likebox

In the past i've succesfuly installed some like boxes, and they are still running right now.
Recently i tried to ad the like box for an other site with the same code and i can't get i to work.

On the like box generator page on facebook will appear the following warning:

> "There was an error fetching the like box for the specified page."

I'm not that familiar with facebook but i'm amazed that sometimes it will work and sometimes i'll get this warning.

Comment: And the page you're trying to generate the like box is a) publicly visible and b) published  ? If this is happening consistently you should file a bug report in Facebook's bug tracker